# Check if a string is superstring of any of the strings in a list

Tags: python, substring

I have a list of strings and another (key) string. I want to check if any of the strings in the list is the sub-string of the key. I can obviously write the trivial traverse and check loop but I want to know if there is a better (more Pythonic) way of doing so.

```
eg. 
list: ["ab", "bac"]
key: "backer"
output: True
```

etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `any`:

```
lst = ["ab", "bac"]
key = "backer"

>>> any(item in key for item in lst)
True
```